# Bar Plot in Pandas for 2 categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data something like this (shown in image). I want to plot a bar graph for each region on the x - axis and the number of yes and no for that category (preferably a stacked one). I wrote the following code

```
ax1 = df2.groupby(['US Region'])['Daily Weather Report'].value_counts().plot.bar(stacked = True);
```

and got the following output. Is there a way that i can represent this in a better manner. Stacked plot isnt working.

Data set : https://i.stack.imgur.com/scE8N.png
Output I got :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXGE.png

Comment: Raw data would have been useful. Please the suggested answer and lets know. If doesnt work shout out.

Comment: Please accept the answer if happy so that someone having a similar problem can confidently use the same information. Can do that by clicking next to the 2 arrows on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the data in an easily readbale format, it is hard to help.

Please try

```
ax1 = df2.groupby(['US Region'])['Daily Weather Report'].value_counts().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked = True)
```